# Evaluation on Binary Outcome data

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Let us say that we have an experiment where people are shown images of tyres from car/bike and have to tell what it really belongs to.

The objective of the experiment is to validate the hypothesis that people from age group 25-35 are much better at recognizing that the tyre images are from car or bikes.

So the final data that is obtained is as follows

Sample data for the same would be : Bike = 0 Car = 1

```
-------------------------------------
AGE    Actual_Image  Predicted_Image 
-------------------------------------    
15         0              1
27         1              1
34         0              0
55         1              0
```

What is the correct way to see if the hypothesis is correct or not ?

Since I am a beginner in this field some links would be appreciated. I have looked at `chi-square test` for the same but am unable to understand how to apply it in this problem.

As a secondary question I would also like to know if `d-prime` value can help in this ? For example if I calculate d prime value for each group and say that the group having the highest d-prime value is the best at recognizing the images ?

P.S : Not any homework/test. Looking to learn more about validating hypothesis/ significance value etc.

Comment: Are you showing equal numbers of cars and bikes?  Do the subjects answer equal numbers of cars and bikes (unlikely)?  And are both groups shown the same set of images?

Comment: Hey Corone....If you are talking about the database, then yes it contains equal number of cars and bikes images. If the experiment is designed in terms of 10 groups : each group having unique images of bikes and cars, people across groups are not unique ie they can answer different groups also. Thus equal numbers of cars and bikes is not true per subject.

Comment: I think the research hypothesis is not well formulated. You have a well-defined group (age 25-35) and you suppose they are better at recognizing the tyres. But better than what? The average performance of all other people? This might be rather misleading. Or better than any other age group of similar size? Or better than any other non-overlapping age groupf of similar size? Or better than any set of people consisting of people of an age in a arbitary age set not containing 25-35?

Comment: @Erik I can always change the age groups of users to be as 1,2,3,4 where in 1 determines the age-group 0-5, 2 determines the age group 5-15 etc. The hypothesis would be that people in age group 4 (25-35) perform better than people in other age group ?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is make a graph with "age" on the x-axis and "percent correct" on the y-axis. Depending on how much data you have, different graphs could be appropriate, but I would want to add a smooth line to this.

Then, since your hypothesis is that the relationship between age and percent correct is non-monotonic, I would look at a logistic regression where "percent correct" is the dependent variable and a spline of age is the independent variable (since you seem to have age in years, not in groups). Another alternative is to add a transform of age such as "distance from ideal group" which could be whichever is greater of a) the absolute value of age - 15 or b) the absolute value of age - 25.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong but isn't logistic regression used to predict the outcome of a test ? Can it be used in hypothesis testing ( to determine with some confidence that this hypothesis is more correct ). That is why I had asked about `d-prime`

Comment: Logistic regression can certainly be used to test hypotheses.